# Frequent requests with React and Express GraphQL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, asynchronous, graphql

I'm creating a website using React and Express GraphQL, with a MariaDB database. I've come across a problem with making frequent requests/subscriptions to the GraphQL API, however.

After the page in question loads in React, I call this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        waitingTimer: setInterval(this.queryWaiting.bind(this), 1000)
    });
}
```

where `queryWaiting` is a function that carries out a `fetch` request to my GraphQL server at `localhost:3000/graphql`. That URL itself is a proxy defined in my `setupProxy.js` file which proxies the URL from `localhost:4000/graphql`, so that I don't need to use CORS.

It's worth noting that I also `clearInterval` this `waitingTimer` in `componentWillUnmount`.

In my GraphQL server file, which I'm simply running with `node`, I set up my server like this:

```
var app = express();

app.use("/graphql", graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true,
}));
app.listen(4000);
```

Where `schema` is a valid schema, and `root` is my root resolver.

The API query that I'm repeatably calling is called `getWaitingCount`, and it acts like this:

```
getWaitingCount: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;

        if (cachedWaitingTime + cachedWaitingInterval > currentTime) {
            return cachedWaiting;
        }

        connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM profiles WHERE isWaiting=1;", function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error)
                reject(error);
            else {
                // Update cache values
                cachedWaiting = results[0]["COUNT(*)"];
                cachedWaitingTime = Date.now() / 1000;
                resolve(cachedWaiting);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I've implemented some caching to reduce server load. The caching variables are defined elsewhere.

The problem I experience is that, after between 2-10 seconds, the POST requests for this specific query from my React app stop getting resolved, and I have to reload the page for them to start getting accepted again. Weirdly, other requests go through fine.

I've tried various solutions, such as switching to using the proxy method I'm using currently, and I've also considered the possibility of a built-in anti-DDOS mechanism in the Express code, but I can't find any evidence for that.

Any help with this issue is very much appreciated.

Comment: why not just use subscription?

Comment: @dan-klasson I don't know, I'm very new to React. Do you have a link that could help me get started?

Comment: It's GraphQL related. Check out the docs for your client and server

Comment: Thanks. I've found some documentation on how to set up subscriptions. But do I really need to, though? Are there any huge downsides to using regular client update requests instead?

Comment: Well you would have to constantly poll it every X seconds no?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not expecting massive traffic. Could 100 queries per second really overwhelm the server?

Comment: No. But that's what subscriptions are for. But whatever works.

Comment: Fair enough. I may implement subscriptions in the future when I have time, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the best solution is to type out and explain your code :)

This code:

```
if (cachedWaitingTime + cachedWaitingInterval > currentTime) {
    return cachedWaiting;
}
```

is inside a promise, so really, it should do:

```
resolve(cachedWaiting);
```

instead of returning it.

That is all. I am currently kicking myself.